# How to use external mouse and keyboard normally in bootcamp with windows 7?

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, mouse

I just installed windows 7 using bootcamp.

I then connected an external keyboard and mouse. I understand that I need to change settings in order to use right click on the trackpad. My problem is that my external mouse's right click does not even work.

How do I enable right click on my external mouse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows on my MacBook, but I think this is what you are looking for

http://realitypod.com/2010/08/solved-right-click-in-windows-xp-vista-7-running-on-macbook/